# How to make music flow between activities. (Android)

Tags: android

I made a music class that will play a song.

I have made onResume and onStop methods in activities so that the song will play.

However, when i switch between activities the the music stops and starts, therefore it is very chopping. How can I make it so that the music flows between the activities, and does not stop and start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `Service` that plays your music in the background. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html.

Here's an example that plays an audio file in the background using the mentioned Service. http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html.